# Finding the number of values from users not in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I want to have a function that looks at an array of users and gets the total number of 1's from users not in that array. The default is Group1 so I want to count all of the Group1 1's and all the 1's from users not in the list at all. My formula so far is `=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D11:D19,G11:H14,0)))*(A11:C19=1))`

The match function doesn't seem to work when I have a 2D array as a parameter though. For the example below, the output should be 6.

[image: example sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match does not work with two Dimensional Arrays.

Use COUNTIF instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(G11:H14,D11:D19)=0)*(A11:C19=1))
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason I had to remove the =0, possibly a glitch. But other than that worked great thanks!

Comment: `=0` Will give you the count where the names are `NOT` in the list.  `>0` will give the count when the names are in the list.  By deleting you run the risk of errors if the name is found twice in the list.